# Delete unwanted files uploaded on navigate away Best Practice

Tags: asp.net, image, image-uploading

Hi I am in a great confusion.
I have a page that accepts multiple [image uploads](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317) say max 5.
I added some additional functionality like after selecting required files when the user hits "Upload All" button, the images get saved to the App_Images folder and the page displays a placeholder with the images uploaded.

Everything is okay up to this point.

**Big Problem**

When the user navigates away with out hitting the final "Submit" button (which completes the actvity of posting an item say story/comic on the page), the images were still saved. And I want to delete them.
I don't want to use client script "Are you sure Navigate Away from this Page?" kinda things. ( If it is the only alternative, I tried onbefore unload and I am unable to implement it perfectly for deleting images. I need to think of this.)

**My thought**

1. Is there any way to implement a functionality to show the uploaded images from the user machines itself and on the click of submit button I would like to save them to the App_Images folder?
2. Can I do like saving them to a folder called App_Temp folder and on the hit of submit I can save them to App_Images folder and delete them from App_Temp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spontaneously I'd save the images in a temp folder and move them to the production directory upon submit. And then clean the temp folder at given times where the images are old enough to be orphans.

//JaggenSWE

Comment: But the temp folder you are mentioning about might be on the client's machine right?

Comment: The temp folder will be on the server as well. Otherwise the answer that Dan gives below can be implemented as well, given that you don't need the image files on the server BEFORE the final submit.

Comment: Dan's answer is similar to my 2nd thought mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to rearrange things so the image uploads happen when the user presses the 'final submit' button.